# Query jsonb column to match an array of keys

Tags: json, postgresql, matching, jsonb, postgresql-9.5

I have a table `items` which has a jsonb column `data`.

The `data` column is something like this `{"name": "aaa", "age": 23, "job": "dev"}`.

How do I select items that the `data` has only the keys `name`, `age`?.

Comment: Postgres version?

Comment: Hi @LeninRajRajasekaran, I'm using postgres version 9.5.14

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `?` and the `?&` operators.

For your usecase, it will be:

```
SELECT * FROM table WHERE (NOT data ? 'job') AND (data ?& array ['name', 'age'])
```

Comment: thanks @Lenin, I just test it. This will still select items that has ['name', 'age', 'job']. How do I select items that has exact array of keys?

Comment: yeah, I read the document you sent and tried with ?&. It still selects other items. Weird

Answer (score 0):

Use the [delete operator `-`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.5/functions-json.html), example:

```
with items (data) as (
values
    ('{"name": "aaa", "age": 23}'::jsonb),
    ('{"name": "aaa", "age": 23, "job": "dev"}'),
    ('{"name": "aaa", "age": 23, "gender": "f"}')
)

select *
from items
where data - 'name'- 'age' = '{}'

            data            
----------------------------
 {"age": 23, "name": "aaa"}
(1 row)
```

In Postgres 10+ you can use a text array:

```
select *
from items
where data - array['name', 'age'] = '{}'
```